# 404 facebook like link

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, http-status-code-404, facebook-like

I want to add a like link for all product on http://www.baleine-bleue.de/
but all created links return a 404 in the debugger. In the Browser the pages are running.

I have tested this [link](http://www.baleine-bleue.de/kinderspielzeug-spielzeug-kinder/sommer-html/vilac-dosenwerfen-kinderparty-spiel-chamboule-tout.html) in the Debugger (developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Have you any idea?

Comment: There are no OpenGraph tags on your pages. And, are you sure your site doesn't block the FB crawler?

Comment: How can I find out, if my page blocks the FB crawler? Can't find something in the robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#crawl

The FB crawler uses one of

```
facebookexternalhit/1.0
facebookexternalhit/1.1
```

as user agent. You should be able to verify in your webserver's access logs whether you received a hit or not when you access

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.baleine-bleue.de%2F
```

Seems strange that the final url is reported as http://www.baleine-bleue.de/178.77.92.236 Is this correct?